# Recovering inspector values from Unity build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made the stupid mistake of moving a C# script out of the project and back in. This, of course, cleared all of the important inspector values back to their default values from the script.

All I need is to see those values again and re-enter them. I attempted decompiling the assembly-csharp.dll from my last build using dotPeak. While this did recover the correct classes and their fields, all of the fields are not defined. Where in a Unity build are these values stored, and is it possible to decompile them there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are stored in the scene file (.unity) or, if it's a prefab, in the prefab file (.prefab) (and if it's a prefab in the scene, it's stored in the prefab file with a list of modifications in the scene file). You might have success finding some values in there, but those are serialized and you can only really read them with Asset Serialization Mode "Force Text". It might also be that they lose their value when you open Unity between moving the script out and moving it back in.

Edit:
I missed the part that you wanted to read them from the build. I don't think that's possible, as they are normally serialized (if they are not in Streaming Assets). As scene files (which I think would contain the data) are also just files and not scripts that get compiled, I think the values are in one of the serialized files.
Also: You don't happen to have any kind of version control? Because then you could rollback to an old commit that contains that data, or if that's not possible look at the specific file in question.

Comment: Thanks! Editing .unity file via notepad works perfect and shows all lost data.